# Parallelogram in C++ Using While or Do/While

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have an assignment requiring a program that creates a parallelogram of a specific size and makeup. I need to use at least one for loop and one while or do/while loop. So far, I've created a program that does this:

```
Enter the symbol to use to draw your parallelogram: 
+
Enter the number of symbols to use for each side: 
5

+
++
+++
++++
+++++
++++
+++
++
+
```

Great, but not a parallelogram. It should do this:

```
+
++
+++
++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
+++++
_++++
__+++
___++
____+
```

Ignore the underscores- I was just using them to create spaces.

I think I need to create a while or do/while loop that says, "Once you've gotten to the specified number (in the above case, 5), print that row 5 times." Then I need to create another for loop that says, "Once you've done that while or do/while loop, start subtracting characters from the left side until you get back to one."
Can someone give me an idea of how to do this or even if this idea is a good one? My current code is below. The //while (row=length) bit is my started attempt at a while, which is why I have it as a comment right now. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int length;
    char symb;

    cout <<"Enter the symbol to use to draw your parallelogram: "<<     endl;
    cin >> symb;
    cout <<"Enter the number of symbols to use for each side: "<< endl;
    cin >> length;

    int row, col;
    for (row=0; row<=length; row++) //Up and over row
    {
        for (col=0; col<=row; col++) //Up and over column
            cout << symb;
        cout << endl;
    }
    //while (row=length)
    //{


    for (row=length; row>=1; row--) //Down and over row
    {
        for (col=row; col>=1; col--) //Down and over column
            cout << symb;
        cout << endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: The first line should print one symbol, the next should print three, then next five... I'm sure you can see a pattern emerging. Then just work on the initial spacing (it's equally simple with a similar pattern).

Comment: For some similar examples, you can search StackOverflow for "c++ print triangle".  These use `for` loops and not `while` loops.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the expected output, please don't put formatted text like code or output in comments.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 
Edited at your request!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews
Unfortunately, I need to use at least one for loop and at least one while or do/while loops.  I think I have the for part at least partially down, but I'm required to use at least one while or do/while.

Comment: You need *three* loops, those two you have now for the beginning and the end, and also one in the middle for the parallel part.

Comment: You can change a `for` loop into a `while` loop: generally, `for (A; B; C) S` => `A; while (B) { S; C; }`.  Hint: for each line in the last part of the parallelogram you need to print the right number of spaces before printing the right number of symbols.

Comment: I'm guessing I need to add something that prints whitespace before the last cout << symb;.  I have no clue how to do that.  Is it something that would be included in that part or a separate line?